# Compilation error C++ undefined reference

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm a beginner and I'm currently feeling pretty lost about a compilation error that I'm getting since yesterday, so I was hoping someone could help me. I'm writing the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


void heapify(int);
void print(int);

const int MAX = 10;

int main () {
  int arr[MAX] = {2, 3, 4, 1, 12, 34, 11, 9, 22, 5};


  print(arr[MAX]);
  heapify(arr[MAX]);
  print(arr[MAX]);

  return 0;
}


void heapify(int arr[]) {
  int i = 0;
  int l = 2 * i;
  int r = 2 * i + 1;

for (i = 0; i < ::MAX; i++) {
  if (l <= i/2 && arr[l] > arr[i/2]) {
   std::swap(arr[l], arr[i/2]); 
    }
  if (r <= i/2 && arr[r] > arr[i/2]) {
    std::swap(arr[r], arr[i/2]);
    } 
  }
}

void print(int arr[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ::MAX; i++) {
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I'm then compiling it using the g++ -c main.cpp and g++ -o main main.cpp commands but I get the following compilation errors:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to 'print(int)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to 'heapify(int)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to 'print(int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've looked up the type of error and I get that whenever I am getting a compilation error like undefined reference to main c++ or undefined reference to a c++ function then I have to add definition of that function inside my file. I'm probably in the wrong but it seems to me that I have defined my functions correctly, though the program won't be executed successfully. I've consulted similar questions on StackOverflow about this error and, as far as I've seen, most of them have as a cause a missing .cpp file but I'm just compiling the main.cpp file so I don't really know what to do.

By any chance, can anyone point out what am I getting wrong?

Comment: `void heapify(int);` is a different function than `void heapify(int arr[]) `

Comment: Look closely at your calls to those functions. You are not passing the array, you are passing a single element of the array, and one outside the range of the array.

Comment: I think you need to take a couple of steps back, and refresh the chapters about arrays in your text-books. And learn about `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the two declaration of `heapify`.

The one before `main`:

```
void heapify(int);
```

The one after main (which is also a definition):

```
void heapify(int arr[]) { ...
```

It might not be totally obvious, but these two declarations declare two different functions, both named `heapify` but with different parameter types. One accepts an `int` and another accepts an `int *` (cleverly disguised as `int []` -- in case of function parameters (but not elsewhere!) these two things are the same). Both can happily coexist in a single program. This is called "overloading". It is a powerful tool, but you don't need it here. You need *one* function named `heapify`, not two.

The compiler complains about the first function, `heapify(int)`, which is never defined.

So fix the first declaration to have the same parameter types as the other one:

```
void heapify(int []);
```

The same goes for `print`.

Now if you try to compile your program, you will get compilation
errors. That's because the calls to `heapify` and `print` are wrong.

When you *declare* an array, you put the size in the square brackets:

```
int arr[MAX];
```

When you *use* and array, you *don't* put the size in the square brackets. To refer to a single element, you put its index in a square brackets:

```
int first = arr[0]; // for example.
```

To refer to the *whole* array, you don't use square brackets at all:

```
heapify(arr);
```

If you write `arr[MAX]`, the following happens.

1. The compiler treats `MAX` as just another index, no different from `0` or `1` or `l/2` or anything else.
2. It generates code to access the element with the index `MAX`, *which does not exist*. Valid indices are `0` to `MAX-1`. Accessing `arr[MAX]` is *undefined behaviour*. At run time the program would have crashed or produced unexpected results (or sometimes, by pure chance, *expected* results -- but only when you are looking at it, not when your professor is looking). So it's pretty bad. *However...*
3. The *type* of `arr[anything]` is `int`, regardless of whether it exists or not. When you write `heapify(arr[MAX])`, the compiler generates a call to `heapify(int)`. *But this function was never defined*. You defined `heapify(int[])` which is a totally different function. And of course at the linking stage `heapify(int)` is not found.

Fix the calls to `heapify` and `print` and the program should compile. (I have not tested it so I don't know if it *works*).